# Is there a way to judge whether all the events have been consumed?

Tags: disruptor-pattern

Is there a way to judge whether all the events have been consumed? Similar to the BlockingQueue.isEmpty() method. 
I want to add some business logic when consumers are idle.
Looking forward to your reply.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the ringbuffer has [remainingCapacity](https://lmax-exchange.github.io/disruptor/docs/com/lmax/disruptor/RingBuffer.html#remainingCapacity--) which tells you how many slots remain free. So you would then need to compare that to the capacity of the ring buffer to check if its empty.